# How to reproduce an audio signal by frames python?

Tags: python, audio

I'd like to reproduce an audio signal by frames in a loop in python. In order to do that, I've tried with:

```
import sounddevice as sd

#Suppose:
nframes = 750
lframe = 882
fs = 44100

#Loop
for i in range(0,nframes):
    sd.play(signal[i*lframe:(i+1)*lframe].astype('int16'),fs,blocking=True)
```

But I don't hear anything. I have checked that `sd.play(signal.astype('int16'),fs,blocking=True)` works correctly.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: What is `signal.shape`?

Comment: Its shape is (330750,)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming nframes as "number of frames"  and lframe as "length of frame chunk".
In that case nframes < lframe - Do you have typo there?

Lets assume `nframes = 7500` which gives 8 chunks of length 882.

What we need is to create chunks of signal array of length lframe and then play those individually. We change range to xrange as xrange is easier at handling chunks and create signal chunks in steps of lframes and then simply play those.

```
for i in xrange(0, len(signal),lframe):
        sd.play(signal[i:i+lframe].astype('int16'),blocking=True)
```

Full Working Code:

```
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

nframes = 7500
lframe = 882
fs = 44100

samples = np.arange(nframes)/float(nframes)
signal = 10000 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * fs * samples)


for i in xrange(0, len(signal),lframe):
    sd.play(signal[i:i+lframe].astype('int16'),blocking=True)
```

Comment: Good catch that `i` needs to increment by `lframe` each time

Comment: I have checked that I have chunks in each iteration but I don't hear anything

Answer (score 1):

Note that length of `signal = 10000 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * fs * samples)` is the same of length `samples`. In this case the most of junks `signal[i:i+lframe]` are empty.

My working example is:

```
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

lframe = 882 * 10
fs = 44100
frequency = 880

samples = np.arange(0, 1, step=1/fs)
signal = 10000 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * samples)

for i in range(0, fs, lframe):
    sd.play(signal[i:i+lframe].astype('int16'), blocking=True, latency = 'low')
```

In this case `nframes` is not needed because we can calculate it dividing `fs/lframe`.

The main problem is that there is some delay after each `sd.play`. If we take `lframe = 882`, number of frames is 50 per second. The length of every frame is 0.02s which is shorter than delay. Hence I replace `lframe = 882` with `lframe = 882 * 10`.

On my laptop, the minimal multiplier so that I can hear any signal is `lframe = 882 * 8`. Using `latency = 'low'` helped me to reduce it to  `lframes = 882 * 4` to hear some signal.

Comment: It's true, I need the frame to be greater so as to listen something